# How do I make a Home Screen Application not be recreated when pressing the home button

Tags: android

Pardon my dodgy explanation in the title. What happens is: I'm trying to make a home screen application. So far so good, I made the app launcher that launches an application when executed. But, if for example I press the home screen to be taken back to my application, instead of continuing the activity from onResume() it relaunches the application from onCreate();

this is the code i use to launch e new activity:

```
PackageManager pm=getPackageManager();
Intent intent = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(applications.get(c).pname);
startActivity(intent);
```

Any idea how I can make it so that when I press the Home button it doesn't relaunch the whole app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` property on the Activity.

Comment: You are quite right sir! You are a gentleman and a hero! I would treat you to a chocolate muffin but that is quite hard at the moment. Please treat yourself to a chocolate muffin on my behalf. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

@femi

thanks your answer was really great, it was exactly what i was looking for :)

```
<application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:allowTaskReparenting="true"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance">
```